# Query/find features in ArcPad, hide the rest in map?

Tags: arcpad, filter

Trying to help out another department that does quarterly assessments of field data. Their symbology is all set by the status of the assessment (the only way I could figure out how to hide something was to hide symbology) so that doesn't help much. Their checkouts contain all data for the year but they want to be able to filter/limit what is visible in the map based off the quarter (and potentially other data columns). Been trudging through documentation but can't really find anything. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to apply [definition queries](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s50000002z000000.htm) to accomplish what you're after.  Do a read-up at the link I pasted.  It's a very simple technique that's handy for this type of thing.  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you apply a [Definition](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s50000002z000000.htm) query in ArcMap (as @Dano suggests above) it's exported to ArcPad as a [Filter](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcpad/10.0/help/index.html#//00s10000005q000000) meaning all records are present but only those which pass the filter criteria are displayed.

As far as I can see Filters in ArcPad act in pretty much the same way as Definition Queries in ArcMap, except that Filters also have the `@##MAPSCALE##` variable. Good luck!